# Jasper - Oracle - How to filter by date

Tags: sql, oracle, jasper-reports

I am trying to filter a query by date.

I have this line in my query:

```
AND (the_date like CONCAT (TO_DATE($P{THE_DATE}, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'%'))
```

However, I just cannot seem to compare the parameter date to the database date effectively.

Database date is of type DATE. Parameter is of type String.

I've also tried:

```
AND (TO_CHAR(the_date) like CONCAT ($P{THE_DATE,'%')
```

Are my data types wrong? I've tried others but to no avail. Is my query wrong?

I'm using iReport... I looked for some kind of debugging option to see what is actually being executed but didn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to compare DATEs, you need to convert the literal into DATE using **TO_DATE**.

No need to use **LIKE** operator. You could either use**TRUNC** on the DATE column, however, that would suppress any regular **index** usage. It would be better to use a **DATE RANGE condition**.

Remember, DATE has both date and time elements.

For example,

```
WHERE
   the_date >= TO_DATE('14-MAY-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
AND 
   the_date < TO_DATE('14-MAY-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') +1;
```

Instead of literals in above example, you could use your **INPUT** parameter or the local **variable** which you have defined as string.

```
WHERE
   the_date >= TO_DATE(in_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')
AND 
   the_date < TO_DATE(in_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') +1;
```

Comment: I like this idea but it turned out I was passing in the parameter in wrong format - literally took me all day to get it right despite many variations and many repeated efforts. Thanks for you answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

The format stored in the databases was like 12/MAY/15.
Although I am convinced I attempted this in the input parameter which was of type String, this proved to be the magic answer :) my input was '12/MAY/15' and it worked.